# if read server does not respond, then all request go the primary write server in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have set up read/write database connections in laravel for database optimization. I would like to know that if our read server does not respond, then all request should go the primary database write server. is that possible in laravel?
Here is my database.php config file

```
'mysql' => [
            'read' => [
                'host' => '192.168.1.1',
            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => '192.168.1.2'
            ],
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK we can't achieve without extending Laravel core. Basically I believe this kind of problem should be resolved by infrastructure configurations, not by application.

For example, if you are using AWS Aurora, you can use **reader(readonly) endpoint**.

- [【新機能】Amazon Aurora で読み込みエンドポイントが利用可能になりました | Developers.IO](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/amazon-aurora-reader-endpoint/) (Japanese)

If your cluster's writer endpoint is `cluster1.cluster-xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, the reader one will be available with suffix **`*-ro`**: `cluster1.cluster-ro-xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`.

Reader endpoint behaves exactly as you want. Normally, loads are balanced by round-robin scheduling. When a reader crashes, it will be automatically excluded from the network. When a writer crashes, one of the readers is automatically promoted to a writer. It's a very cool feature.